# Can VM's be added to Mesos cluster?

Tags: mesos

I'm trying to understand what Mesos can (and can't) do. It looks to be similar to Kubernetes except that it manages resources other than just containers.

My question is, could one of those resources be VMs?

What I'd like is to add another VM every time a new job comes in. Happy to discuss more details but for now suffice it to say that that's my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default resources are MEM, CPU, Disk, Network so you can create your own containerizer that will launch VMs for those resources. You can also create custom resources such as predefined VMs so your task can claim VMs that are existing on the system.

See also: https://kubevirt.io/